# Can i use $store.commit() in mounted() vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a simple question.
Can I use vuex .commit() in mounted() vuejs?

I can use getters but somehow commit doesn't work...

****Edit****
I have found an issue.
I'm making a leaflet-draw wrapper.
I'm using mounted() hoook to get the wrapper component(child component) in parent component. I've added leaflat-draw vanilla js code in mounted() hook and here's a problem.

- in vanilla js event in mounted() hook, 'this' keyword doesn't work. (=undefined)
  e.g.

  ```
   objectLayer.on("layeradd", function(e) {

            let layer = e.layer;
            layer.on("click", onClickFeatureSelct, layer);
    }
  ```

I didn't have enough time to test cases for other event, so I've posted a question to vue forum:
https://forum.vuejs.org/t/commit-of-undefined-in-mounted-valina-js-event-function/98431

Thanks for the comments guys! :)

Comment: you could show us the code that didnt worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use `this.$store.commit('YOURCOMMITNAME', payload)` in the `created`, `beforeMount` & `mounted` lifecycle hook of any component.

---

EDIT: I am not sure about your use case but if you need to use `this`, you should try fat arrow function. Something like

```
objectLayer.on("layeradd", e => {
    console.log(e, this.$store.getters.test);
    this.$store.commit('setData', payload);
});
```

OR may be define the function first OR try [.bind(this)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

Comment: typo, its `commit`

Comment: @Chawchawchaw You can try the fat arrow function or .bind()

Comment: @Saleem Gosh, fat arrow function worked. what the .. what's the reason???

Comment: @Chawchawchaw You can read - Main benefit: No binding of ‘this’ @ https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/when-and-why-you-should-use-es6-arrow-functions-and-when-you-shouldnt-3d851d7f0b26/

Comment: @Saleem ahh, super clear, Thank you very much for it